# Bubble sort implementation not working

Tags: python, algorithm

This bubble sort algorithm prints an empty list each time it's run, really don't see the problem with it:

```
def bubble_sort(seq):
    changed = True

    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
            if seq[i] > seq[i+1]:
                seq[i], seq[i+1] = seq[i+1], seq[i]
                changed = True
    print(seq)          
    return None         


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bubble_sort(list(range(0,10,-1)))
```

Comment: Generally, you don't want a function like this producing its own output. Have it sort in-place or return a sorted list, leaving the input unchanged. Either way, let the caller decide whether to output the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

`list(range(0, 10, -1))` gives an empty list [] because you range from 0 to 10 with -1 steps...

try `list(range(10, 0, -1))`

```
def bubble_sort(seq):
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
            if seq[i] > seq[i + 1]:
                seq[i], seq[i + 1] = seq[i + 1], seq[i]
                changed = True
    print(seq)
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # l = list(range(0, 10, -1)) # Wrong :-)
    l = list(range(10, 0, -1))
    print l
    bubble_sort(l)
```

results in

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

UPDATE: if you want to do it recursively, but no cheating :-)...

```
def bubble_sort(input_list):
    for idx, num in enumerate(input_list):
        try:
            if input_list[idx + 1] < num:
                input_list[idx] = input_list[idx + 1]
                input_list[idx + 1] = num
                bubble_sort(input_list)
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return input_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = [100, 39, 2, 12, 42, 12, 90]
    bubble_sort(my_list)
    print(my_list)
```

Comment: Thaks! It works perfectly!